# Ranking Formula

Tags: excel, vba

[image: CLICK HERE TO SEE IMAGE]

I want to do a user ranking basis on logged In count, higher is best.

I used rank formula for this. I got the ranking but if more than one user has same logged In count then same raking no.reflecting. Which is ok.

I want like this only but Next rank is not in continuation.

I want formula for this..e.g. in image 3 users are in 1 rank but next rank started at 4. It should show 2 next.

Kindly provide the resolution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This array formula will rank them in order without skipping numbers

```
=SUM(IF(B2<$B$2:$B$10,1/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,$B$2:$B$10)))+1
```

Being an Array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: It helps.. Thanks a ton

Comment: @skroutela please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: I have a data of 20000 users, Array formula is taking too much time to output the result and also slowing down the excel... Is there any other solution?

Comment: only other option is vba @skroutela

Comment: Or you can sort your data on the Login Count and use a normal formula then copy and paste the values back.  The sort it back the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for valuable answers Scott

Comment: Again i have a small concern that i have four filed in sheet, 1. unique id, 2. Name, 3. submission 4. Rank and data under these columns are called through formula also have the drop down option in filed so that if I change the value in drop down then data of all four column gets changed.. also filter is not working here... do you have any solution for this... plz share